# How to get List for Contact Form 7

Tags: shortcode, contact-form-7

I have 2 contact forms created by Contact Form 7.
How to list all contact forms created through shortcode?
Please check images, tks.

[image: list]

[image: dropdown]

**Updated:** 
this is my code, this working!

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$rs = array();
if( $data = get_posts($args)){
    foreach($data as $key){
        $rs[$key->ID] = $key->post_title;
    }
}else{
    $rs['0'] = esc_html__('No Contact Form found', 'text-domanin');
}
```

Comment: Hi, i want a same result as your, did you get the result by any chance? can you please share it with me?

Comment: Yes, i updated my question, Hope these help!

Comment: Thanks, this one work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a dropdown list:

```
<select name="field-name" id="field-id"> 
    <option value="">--Select--</option><?php
    $dbValue = get_option('field-name'); //example!
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'     => 'wpcf7_contact_form',
        'numberposts'   => -1
    ));
    foreach ( $posts as $p ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$p->ID.'"'.selected($p->ID,$dbValue,false).'>'.$p->post_title.' ('.$p->ID.')</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```